# Sharepoint 2013 disable access to list through address bar /lists/

Tags: list

I want to know if there are any solution to disable the access to the list through the address bar.

```
http://monsite/lists/maliste/allitems.aspx
```

I have create webpart and I want the users edit the list only through the webpart and event when they put the link through the address bar they don't have access.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest two steps solution:
1) Make list hidden in "View all site content" view. You can achieve this using SharePoint designer or by setting SPList.Hidden property using server object model.
2) If first step is not enough you can add Content Editor web part to your default list view (or all views) and add javasscript to redirect from list.

Answer (score 0):

Thank, The solution work but if we have 200 SPList and each list with three views so it's a lot of work to add manually rediection for each view.

in the publishing website hoew we can disable the access to the backend like site content, list of web pages , style...

Keep sharepoit work list a advanced website without any administration features.

Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: You can trim user's permissions so he won't be able to use administrative features like "Site Actions" but you cannot restrict access to "View all site content".